# How to call another worker from sidekiq worker and monitor its progress without pausing child worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, worker

I am currently calling Worker2 from Worker1 and trying to monitor the progress of Worker2. The problem is, the way I'm monitoring the progress for Worker2 (through a while loop) is causing Worker2 to never run.

Here's what I've got:

```
    Worker2.perform_async(@project_assessment.id)

    while true
        if @project_assessment.project.status != 'completed'
            sleep 20
        end
    end
    generate_report
    notify_user
```

Worker2 never actually runs because of my while loop. However, Worker2 is going to update the project status to completed when it's finished, so how do I properly monitor this without affecting the performance of Worker2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking here is something similar to [Sidekiq Workflow](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Complex-Job-Workflows-with-Batches). But this is available only on Sidekiq-Pro version, which is paid.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help! Will figure out an alternative way to implement this.